# jQuery autocomplete strange behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I've got an issue with jQuery's autocomplete. What I am trying to do is show a suggestions list based on input. So, for instance, on `input class="font"` I want to have a list of font sizes and on `input class="color"` to have a list of color predictions.

Here is what I have:

```
function suggestions(input, element) { 
  var suggestions = [];
  if (element.hasClass("color") !== -1) {  
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 100) {
      suggestions.push("color" + i.toString()); // for testing purpose
    i++;
    }
  } else {
      var nr = 1;
      while (nr < 1025) {
        suggestions.push(nr.toString() + "px");
        nr = nr + 1;
      }
  }

  $(element).autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: function (request, response) {
      var counter = 0;
      var filteredArray = $.map(suggestions, function (item) {
        if (item.startsWith(request.term) && counter < 10) {
          counter = counter + 1;
          return item;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      });
      response(filteredArray);
    },
    autoFocus: true
  });
}
```

The thing is, it works perfectly when I test it for inputs having any class except 'color'. When it detects a class with 'color', it will build the suggestions array accordingly but will refuse to get into the anonymous function inside autocomplete - source. Which is odd to me, 'cause the array is always constructed and the autocomplete should always be hit.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: You are using function name and var name same as suggestions

Comment: Only for exemplification purposes. My code was a bit different. But thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's `.hasClass()` returns boolean value, so you code should look like:

```
if (element.hasClass("color")) { ... }
```

Try this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/3n4yhh6a/) (type symbol "c")

Comment: I firstly sent the element as the input's class, instead of sending the element itself and I was using `element.indexOf("color")` instead, that's why I ended up posting it like that. However, in my code I still had the version without `hasClass` and your answer lightened the bulb: why not sending the whole element instead of its class? Now it works just like expected! Thanks :)